# Develop windows app in Kotlin using Android STUDIO

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

Is it possible to develop a Kotlin app for windows using Android Studio?

I can't seem to find an option but was wondering if it is possible somehow since AS is built on Intellij.

Comment: Yep you can, intellij is made entirely on swing, read more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309569/what-gui-libraries-are-the-jetbrains-using). They've worked hard making their own components.

Comment: I'd use intellij though

Comment: You can, but Android Studio doesn't include project templates for it. But if you had a bare project template, you can import that and it works fine.