# Can't build project with maven and graalvm

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, graalvm, exec-maven-plugin

What did I do wrong?
Trying to build native-image app following [this](https://www.graalvm.org/dev/reference-manual/native-image/guides/use-native-image-maven-plugin/) graalvm guide.But I can't.

Maybe it lacks some linking inside project...
I'm working in IntellijIDEA and it says, that I can't use  where I use it. From net seraching I concluded, that it isn't important, but maybe there is my problem?
Here is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>java-agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>java</executable>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                        <classpath/>
                                        <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>${project.build.directory}/${imageName}</executable>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${native.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <fallback>false</fallback>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <arg>-H:DashboardDump=fortune -H:+DashboardAll</arg>
                            </buildArgs>
                            <agent>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                <options>
                                    <option>experimental-class-loader-support</option>
                                </options>
                            </agent>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>adianov.sergei</groupId>
    <artifactId>COVID-Risk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>COVID-Risk</name>

    <properties>
        <native.maven.plugin.version>0.9.18</native.maven.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.specification.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.specification.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <imageName>COVID Risking</imageName>
        <mainClass>MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <to>
                        <image>docker.io/heartofglass404/COVID_Risking</image>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>adianov.sergei.covidrisk/adianov.sergei.covidrisk.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And error:

> [ERROR] Command execution failed.
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Comment: that error does not have the details for what error graalvm getting, can you share longer stacktrace or a reproducer would be easier to see the error.

Comment: Here is full trace https://github.com/graalvm/native-build-tools/issues/385

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building javaFX with graalVM I used [gluonhq](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples), looks like Gluon is the responsible of javaFX at [here](https://openjfx.io/highlights/19/) they say

> Kudos go to the fine people at Gluon who took care of the bulk of the work on JavaFX 19. Do check their JavaFX Long Term Support services.

I tried to fix your reproducer first but it has so many maven plugin configured it was confusing and bulky so I created a clean pom xml from [gluon start page](https://start.gluon.io) then added your reproducer and required configuration. [Here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/blob/master/CovidRisk/pom.xml) is the result.

Most important part is below

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        <attachList>
            <list>display</list>
            <list>lifecycle</list>
            <list>statusbar</list>
            <list>storage</list>
        </attachList>
        <bundlesList>
            <list>adianov.sergei.covidrisk</list>
        </bundlesList>
        <reflectionList>
            <list>adianov.sergei.covidrisk.RootLayoutController</list>
            <list>adianov.sergei.covidrisk.PersonOverviewController</list>
            <list>adianov.sergei.covidrisk.PersonEditDialogController</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.Button</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.CheckBox</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.ComboBox</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.Menu</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.MenuBar</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.MenuButton</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.MenuItem</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.Separator</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.Slider</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.SplitPane</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableView</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableColumn</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TextArea</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TextField</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.image.ImageView</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.layout.GridPane</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.layout.HBox</list>
        </reflectionList>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It was annoying to add those classes one by one, otherwise native image throws class not found exception.

I tried to use graalvm native maven plugin but for javafx we can not use that because javafx requires extra libraries which is covered by gluon plugin and one more thing I needed to use [gluon graalvm](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases)

I used [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) for gluon graalvm installation

```
sdk list java
sdk install java 22.1.0.1.r17-gln
```

I had one more problem related to compile was "not found libraries", to fix that I used

```
sudo apt install libasound2-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libgl-dev libgtk-3-dev libpango1.0-dev libxtst-dev
```

found the apt command from [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/). To be honest my expectation from javaFX was higher. It is hard to compile and have a result with it, Swing looks easier even [they say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10589875/175554) javaFX is strong. After all intellij still [uses swing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311981/175554).

This is how it looks in my computer
[image: How look]

Comment: Oh, that's a lot of work! Thank you for your efforts.
So, after starting just from scratch and even NOT using native-image, just to build some runnable jar – stubled against jlink error, because I'm using apache poi and it has filename-based automodules that is not allowed to use with jlink. Maybe I'm just really overcomplify this application and it can be done much simplier...
But, thanks again, you give me a few new thoughts on what's going on and how to fix it